# Data missing when sent via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to send two values to my PHP script that is being called from an AJAX request. Somehow my data is not being passed to the PHP script.

Maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere. Can I have some insight?

```
    $(function() {

        $(".delbutton").click(function() {
                var viewed_comments = $("#viewed_comments").val();
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");

                var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                var comments = 'comm=' + viewed_comments;
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');  

            if (confirm("Are you sure to mark this as viewed?")) {

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "update_entry.php", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {info:info, comments:comments },

                    success : function(response) {

                           if(response=="updation success"){
                           console.log('inside');


                           }
                    }
                });  
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And my PHP where the AJAX request is going,

```
    $id     =   $_POST['id'];
  $viewed_comments = $_POST['comm'];
  $level_code  = $_SESSION['level_code'];
  $action   =   'view';
  $viewed_date = date("Y-m-d");    
  $viewed_by        =    $_SESSION['session_admin_id'] ;

  if($action    == 'view')
  { 
   $viewed_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');  

   $nots = $db->idToField("tbl_table","notes",$id);
   if ($nots == "")
   {
   $date_string = "last viewed on|".$viewed_date."|" ;
   }
   else {
   $date_string = $nots."last viewed on|".$viewed_date."|" ;
   }
      $fnc->update_is_viewed_for("tbl_table",$id, "$viewed_date", $viewed_by);        
    $notes_data = array("notes"=>$date_string,"viewed_comments"=>$viewed_comments);
    $db->query_update("tbl_table", $notes_data, "id=$id");
     }
    if($db->query_update("tbl_table", $notes_data, "id=$id")){
      http_response_code();        
      echo json_encode('updation success');
    }else{
       http_response_code(204);       
    }
```

Comment: Can you post PHP code?

Comment: How have you confirmed the data isn't being sent?  When you inspect the HTTP request in your browser's debugging tools, is the data not there?  What is there?

Comment: The JS seems fine in isolation. How have you debugged this to determine if the values are missing in the JS or the PHP?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Just updated, please take a look

Comment: @David I am not sure about how to detect that. Can you help me doing that

Comment: @Andy for detect use console google, right click dev google - console and see if consol say 'success'

Comment: @Andy: In Chrome, press F12.  There are *many* debugging tools available to you there.  Specifically in this case go to the Network tab and you can observe the entire requests/responses for your AJAX (and any other requests being made).

Comment: if you're returning json object, you should mention dataType: "Json" in ajax

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yeah I checked, its not showing ''success''

Comment: after url: "update_entry.php" add         dataType: "json", //the return type data is json

Comment: @Andy: Where are you even trying to *use* these values (`info` and `comments`) server-side?  In what specific way is this code not working as expected?  Please include information about the observed request and response in your browser's debugging tools.  Also check the browser's development console for any errors.  You may be unfamiliar with these tools, but this is exactly the time to start using them.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a name thing? You send two POST variables:

```
data: {
          info: info,
          comments: comments
        },
```

but you retrieve them with different names:

```
    $id     =   $_POST['id'];
  $viewed_comments = $_POST['comm'];
```

What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: WHere to do this `var_dump($_POST);` . I did on PHP script but it shows nothing

Comment: It does need to be in the PHP, but you must then display the return from it in your JS, so you might need to force a "success" response from the script. No idea how you do that.

Comment: @Andy: *"it shows nothing"* - Where are you looking?  If it's in the PHP script being invoked by the AJAX call then it would be in the response to that call, which your code currently ignores but which you can observe in your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: Or you could change the PHP to use `info` and `comments` instead of `id` and `comm` and see if it starts working?

Comment: @droopsnoot I changed it. But still not into success function

Comment: Not in success function, or not displaying your success message because it hasn't seen the response string? If you put your console.log before the `if`, does it make any difference?

Comment: What is in your `info` and `comments` variables before you call the PHP code? What you expect, or something different? (console.log or alert will show you). As I see it your PHP will receive `$_POST['info']` which contains `"id=whatever"` and `$_POST['comments']` which contains `"comm=somethingelse"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use seriliaze form values it will solve your **data missing problem**, change `#frm` to your form id

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url:"update_entry.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:formValues,
        dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
               if (data == 'updation success') {
                console.log('success');
               }
            }
        });
    });
});
```